Правило noindex
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/block-indexing?hl=ru
Не понимаю, собираюсь выставить тег на запрет индексирование страницы. На страницы которые отдают 404 ошибку.
К примеру в robots.txt, прописано
User-agent: *
Disallow: */page/*

Если на странице '/page/' выставить тег
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">

Следуя

Внимание! Чтобы правило noindex работало, файл robots.txt не должен
блокировать поисковому роботу доступ к странице. В противном случае
поисковый робот не сможет обработать ее код и не обнаружит правило
noindex. В результате контент с такой страницы по-прежнему будет
появляться в результатах поиска, например если на нее ссылаются другие
ресурсы.

То есть, я тут смотрю по статистике сканирования в гугл консоле, ищу страницы которые отдают 404 код. Каждую страницу прописываю запрет на обход в файле robots и чтобы избавиться от этой волокиты. Решаю выставить в html документе, запрет на индексирование. Как только выставлю тег, все страницы что запретил robots, снова попадут в поиск?
У меня количество загруженных страниц 8000 в гугл консоле из них 400 проиндексированные, остальные это мусор. Пытаюсь выровнять количество загруженных с проиндексированными. Чтобы робот лишний раз не обходил...
Не понимаю, как правильно делать. Страницы отдают 404, они очень долго удаляются. Роботы их постоянно обходят, запрет в robots должен спасти это и в дальнейшем роботы не станут их сканировать и забудут про них...

"Не понимаю, собираюсь выставить тег на запрет индексирование страницы. На страницы которые отдают 404 ошибку." -- ошибка 404 обычно указывает, что сервер не может найти запрошенный ресурс, как Вы собираетесь туда что-то добавлять, если эти страницы поисковик не может найти?

Непонятно какую проблему вы решаете, ошибки 404 в принципе никогда не появятся в результатах поиска и пытаться блокировать их через всякие robots.txt нет смысла. Гораздо интереснее разобраться в том, почему поисковик в принципе начал пытаться ходить по несуществующим страницам

В php, отдаю 404 код если контент страницы был удален. Робот будет все время обходить те страницы которые ранее были проиндексированы. В истории обхода, яндекса гугла, они все время обходят своего рода страницы. В robots прописываю каждую, ок. А тег необходим, чтобы не делать этого, не прописывать каждую страницу в robots. Избавиться от подобного рода волокиты... Только вот если добавлю и в robots запрет на нее. Получается он попрежнему будет обходить....?

@Dmitrii под контекнтом страницы подразумевается сама страница? Если страницы не существует, как Вы планируете добавлять на нее meta-тег?

Сама страница есть, на ней размещалась новость. Новость удалил, теперь страница осталась, отдаю 404 правило http_response_code(404). Прошел год-два, а поисковые роботы попрежнему обходят данную страницу и получают 404. Зачем они это делают, в поиске нет, а продолжают обходить.

Стал в robots.txt добавлять каждую страницу, там уже 2000 строчек. Помогает, не обходят. Как сделать так, чтобы роботы перестали обходить страницы на которых я отдаю 404 код, чтобы не добавлять в robots.

Что мешает возвращать 410 Gone?

Не будет ли конфликта если совместно использовать header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex", true); и http_response_code(404 - 410);

Алгоритм действий со страницами 404:

в robots.txt прописываете:
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /404


noindex не трогаете вообще - он тут не нужен.

идете в GSC, и все страницы 404 удаляете через функцию "удаление".

Не забывайте чистить карту сайта.


Если страница имеет вес (внешние ссылки, соц. сигналы), а вы грохнули на ней контент, ставим с нее 301 на схожую по тематике - все остальное делаем как написано выше.
Если к яше сайт подключен, то также удаляете страницы из поиска.
